# set javascript variable = "variable"

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a javascript variable called `temp`.

ultimately, `temp` will equal one of many strings, let's say for now it equals `"stack"`.

how can I set the variable (in this case `stack`, which is an existing global variable) to equal the string `"stack"`, dynamically?

So if at another point in time, `temp` is set to `"overflow"`, how can i set `overflow = "overflow"`?

Thanks for your help!

i've seen some answers mention `eval` and others mention using bracket ~ `this[variable]`, but can't seem to figure this out..

Comment: I do not know what you mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Variable" Variables in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks, jack! just what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to create an object to hold these dynamic variable assignments.

```
// object to hold temporary variables
var tempVars = {};

// as per your example, we set temp to 'overflow'
var temp = 'overflow';

// now we can set tempVars.overflow
tempVars[temp] = temp;
```

you an then access 'overflow' with either `tempVars.overflow` or `tempVars['overflow']`.  Technically, you *can* assign global variables this way by using the `window` object instead of `tempVars`, but this is a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 1):

Run this and see what happens

```
var x = "something";

window[x] = x;

alert(window.something);
```

This works because javascript objects act like hashtables

But you're best not to use the window object, otherwise you might overwrite something you actually needed.

Comment: Rather, it "works" because global variables are added as properties of the global object. No other execution context (function or eval) does that.